# How to apply a list of functions to a list of arguments using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a function that creates a new array in which each item is a result of a function f(x) from a list of functions.
For example, 
x= [1,2,3]
interFunctions = [f1,f2,f3]
and I want the result to be y = [f1(x[0]),f2(x[1]),f3(x[2])]
The first function is working fine, however, I wanted to use *list comprehension* to do this process, so that my code is not so slow. With my basics skills I tried to used my second function, it returns only one item and I can't get my head around how this list comprehension work for more than one list, can anyone explain to me? 
**First Function**

```
def makeNewYaxisLstofArrays(newXaxisListofArray,lstInterFuncs):        
    for f in lstInterFuncs:
        data = []   
        for x in newXaxisListofArray:
            data.append(f(x))
    return data
```

**Tried using List Comprehension**

```
def makeNewYaxisLstofArrays(newXaxisListofArray,lstInterFuncs):
    for f in lstInterFuncs:
        data = [f(x)for x in newXaxisListofArray]
        for x in newXaxisListofArray:            
    return data
```

Comment: Did you consider [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made a typo in your code, but I guess you wanted to write:

```py
def makeNewYaxisLstofArrays(newXaxisListofArray,lstInterFuncs):
    for f in lstInterFuncs:
        data = [f(x) for x in newXaxisListofArray]
        # for x in newXaxisListofArray: <- I guess it shouldn't be here
    return data
```

The problem with your code is that you're creating `data` for each function. Your code takes the first function from `lstInterFuncs` and applies it to each element from `newXaxisListofArray`. This way in the first run of the loop (for the first element from `lstInterFuncs`) you get `[f1(x1), f1(x2),...]`. Then, you create the list for `f2`: `[f2(x1), f2(x2),...]`, etc. Please note, that each time you overwrite the `data` variable. In the end, your function returns a list for the last function: `[f3(x1), f3(x2), ...]` (given you have 3 functions)

I think you should iterate over both at the same time. In my opinion, you may want to use a `zip()` function -> it can iterate over two lists (or more) at the same time and pack them into a tuple:

```py
def makeNewYaxisLstofArrays(newXaxisListofArray,lstInterFuncs):
    data = [f(x) for f, x in zip(lstInterFuncs, newXaxisListofArray)]
    return data
```

The code will iterate over functions and values simultaneously, so you'll get `[f1(x1), f2(x2), ...]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
x= [1,2,3]
interFunctions = [f1,f2,f3]

y = [f(arg) for f, arg in zip(interFunctions, x)]
```